# JS | replace using function | meaning of (a,b,c)

Tags: javascript, replace

I'm using js's replace function to create an array of items found within a string:

```
var term = "\\bselect\\b([^f]|f(?!rom))*?\\bfrom\\b[\\s]*?\\(";
var modGI = "gi";
var myExp = new RegExp(term, modGI);    
str.replace(myExp, function(a,b,c) { myArr.push(c); return a;} );
```

I can't share str because it is client code.

However, I am using the exact same string in many replace functions and they are all perfectly well accessed within the replace function by this: function(a,b) {do something; return a}; - a returns the text found and b returns the location.

In one case, shown above, b is returning a series of spaces, so myArr is [" ", " ", "   "]. I have to use c to access the number and this works fine. But I don't understand why it's different this time and therefore whether this code is robust.

Can anyone tell me what a, b, and c are meant to pick up?

Thanks

Comment: [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented on MDN:

> ```
> function(match, p1, p2, p3, offset, string) {}
> ```
>
> **match** | The matched substring. (Corresponds to $& above.)
>
> **p1, p2, ...** | The nth parenthesized submatch string, provided the first        argument to replace() was a RegExp object. (Corresponds to $1, $2, etc. above.) For example, if /(\a+)(\b+)/, was given, p1 is the match for \a+, and p2 for \b+.
>
> **offset** | The offset of the matched substring within the total string being examined. (For example, if the total string was 'abcd', and the matched substring was 'bc', then this argument will be 1.)
>
> **string** | The total string being examined.

[See Docs Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)